# In print, what's a good serifed display typeface (with these criteria) to pair with body text in Times?

Tags: fonts, print-design

What typeface would work well for display text, paired with body text in Times?

The criteria are that it should be

- serifed;
- with similar contrast to Times itself, certainly no greater contrast;
- with perhaps a little more weight; and
- with similar length ascenders and descenders relative to x-height.

I was thinking maybe Libre Baskerville, but I dislike its open lowercase *g*, its capital *C*, and its figures (especially *3*). The preference is not to end up using Times itself as the display face :-)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Font choice is very subjective/opinion based, and so there can be no correct answer to this question. However it sounds like you want a display font similar to Times. Georgia is one possibility.